# Makefile decoupled dependencies

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

With the following makefile snippet:

```
main: main.o f1.o f2.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o program main.o f1.o f2.o

main.o: main.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c main.cc

f1.o: f1.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c f1.cc

f2.o: f2.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c f2.cc
```

If I just change one file, only that file get recompiled when I rerun make, as desired. However, I'm having a hard time generalizing this without having to list each file individually. When I try something like:

```
$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $(patsubst %.o,%.cc,$@)
```

It builds each object file individually, but each object file depends on ALL my sources, so a change in any one file causing a full recompile. What's a good way to accomplish this?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html

Comment: [`$<`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) is more concise than `$(patsubst %.o,%.cc,$@)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ismail Badawi commented, [pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html) provide a nice solution. They are a type of [implicit rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html#Implicit-Rules) for make. Basically, implicit rules are automatic recipes based off the file extension. For example, make knows how to convert .c files into .o files implicitly. By default make will run the following recipe for .c files (see the [rule catalogue](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules)):

```
$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c
```

You can modify the process either by setting the variables CC, CPPFLAGS, and CFLAGS, or by defining a pattern rule:

```
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
```

The "$<" above matches the name of the first prerequisite, which will be the .c file in this example. See Beta's comment and [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#Automatic-Variables).

Answer (score 1):

Basically,
you do have to list each `.o` file's dependencies individually.
For example, each `.o` is likely to depend on a different bunch of headers.
Taking your `f1.o`, you need something like:

```
f1.o: include/i.h
f1.o: another.h dir/and-another.h
f1.o: f1.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c f1.cc
```

(you can have as many dependency lines for a target as you like).

Maintaining that list is a nightmare.
Broken dependency lists render your *Makefile* worse than useless—you might as well use a batch file.

All is not lost!
If you are tidy,
you can get the [compiler to do it automatically](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/),
and pretty much for free.
Makes your *Makefile* tidier to boot.
Win Win.